# How to install an older version of OpenCL?

Tags: windows, gpu, opencl, gpgpu

When installing drivers for the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti graphics card on Windows 11, OpenCL version 3.0 is installed.
How can I install OpenCL version 2.0?

Tried installing older versions of NVIDIA drivers but they don't install on Windows 11.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, an older driver is the only way. But you will always get only OpenCL 1.2 with Nvidia. Officially it's 3.0, but 3.0 is just a renaming of 1.2, and the supported OpenCL C language standard is still 1.2. OpenCL 2.0/2.1/2.2 would have extra functionality (more than 1.2/3.0), but that was never supported by Nvidia.

However, Nvidia recently (somewhere between drivers 511 and 525) upgraded the OpenCL compiler from LLVM 3.4 to NVVM 7. The new NVVM 7 has a couple really bad bugs - I have already reported these and they are working on a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do AMD graphics cards and integrated Intel GPUs support OpenCL 2.0?

Comment: @forreg16 yes, AMD and Intel support OpenCL 2.0 on most of their devices.